# Need help using textual analysis to count words spoken by a given individual

Tags: python, text, text-analysis

I'm working with a number of transcripts for corporate earnings calls, [like this](http://seekingalpha.com/article/3968766-assignment-asgn-peter-t-dameris-q1-2016-results-earnings-call-transcript).  I want to count the number of words spoken by individuals at a firm who have a certain title relative to title number of words spoken.  As you can see, this information is conveyed by header text in bold.

Although my coding experience is limited to be honest, I am learning python to do this.  Does anyone here have any recommendations for how to go about this?

Comment: Please provide your code and a short description of the problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

The basic steps of approaching something like this would be as follows:

1. You'll want to start first by scraping the website content in question. You can use the python `requests` library to do this. In this step you'll download the raw HTML website content into your program .
2. Next you'll need to parse the HTML to make sense out of it. Look up the `beautifulsoup` library for python. This will structure the HTML in your program and allow you to search for certain HTML tags that define page structure.
3. After you have gotten a hold of what you need from the HTML, you can `split` the text into multiple words, count the number of total words, and then even count the number of occurrences of each word using a python `dictionary`.

For further text analysis, also check out the `nltk` library for python.